# 3-year-old says they need to go, then don't go

Tags: toddler, potty-training, lying

My three year old daughter has routinely needed to use the toilet once at the beginning of bed time routine, and again at the end of the routine. However, she's started to say she needs to go at the end of the routine without actually producing anything. This has started happening at nap time too.

I don't want to discourage this kid; she basically trained herself starting almost a year ago, and has had nearly zero accidents... If she's little, and still figuring out the signals, and sometimes thinks she has to go but doesn't, then that's that, and we just have her go when she says she needs to. But the timing and lack of production are getting suspicious, and she's started the normal 3 year old developmental stage of manipulation...

Anyone else encounter this? Do we have her sit (for a timed amount) every time she says she needs to go? Or do we have her try, and not let her interrupt her quiet time to try again later? With the risk she'll go in her pull-up?

Comment: Pretty inventive.   Maybe just let it be the new routine.

Comment: If she is just using the second potty to stretch out bedtime, it may not be worth it to make a fuss.  Eventually she will realize that sitting on a toilet with no toys or fun interaction (don't let her have toys or books for the event) is less fun even than sitting in bed.  My advice is "pick your battles", and this doesn't even qualify as a small skirmish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If she is deciding for herself when she needs to go and is not having accidents, then I don't think you have anything to worry about.  If sitting on the potty at that point in her routine has been something's she's gotten used to, then she is probably just continuing with it since it is familiar.  If she doesn't go, don't give her a hard time.  She may decide before too long that she can forgo that potty stop, as she gains increasing confidence in her ability to judge her own need to go.

Comment: Convenient at nap and bed time.